# cannot display this video mode optimum resolution 1280x1024 60hz

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, video, resolution

PC configuration:

- Quad Core
- 4GB RAM
- 160 GB Hard Disk
- 256 MB 64bit Radeon x1600 series PCI card
- Dell 1908 FP LCD
- Windows 7 Ultimate

Whenever I try to install Windows 8 or Windows 8.1, after booting when Windows 8 logo appear just after that I get an error:

> “cannot display this video mode optimum resolution 1280x1024 60hz”

…or something like that.

After getting that error I restart the PC and it continues with windows 7

I tried many versions of Windows 8.1 but same error. But this error never appear while installing Windows 7 or XP.

As my current Windows 7 screen resolution is 1280x1024(recommended) and is working perfectly.

Comment: And the question is???

Comment: Does this happen in the Windows 8 installation screen?

Comment: Yes Just after windows 8 logo disappear.

Comment: Question is I can't install windows 8 into my pc. Getting error  "cannot display this video mode optimum resolution 1280x1024 60hz"

Comment: I had this issue with 3 monitors, the primary using the DisplayPort card and the other two using a DMS-59 splitter to dual-DVI. One DVI monitor would work and the other would work for a few seconds and then display this error. A workaround was using a DVI to VGA converter on the 3rd monitor, and VGA input on the 3rd monitor, which makes it work consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my Dell 1908 FP LCD.  I was able to resolve it by switching to a DVI-D (dual link) cable.  I was previously using a DVI-D (single link) cable.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem .I fixed it by changing refresh rate of display

Right-click on “Desktop > Display Settings > Choose faulty display > Advanced display settings.”

Or you can directly search "Advanced display settings" in start menu

Then go to: “Advanced display settings > Display adapter settings for Display-n > Monitor tab > Change screen refresh rates.”

In my case I reduced Screen refresh rate from 60hz to 59hz and that fixed the issue.