# Cannot display this video mode, change computer display input to <something>

Tags: linux, video, resolution, xorg

After installing Debian 9, when I try starting X I get the following message: "Cannot display this video mode, change computer display input to 1920x1080@60Hz".
The console (tty) is working however, clearly using a lower resolution.

Here is the output of hwinfo --framebuffer:

```
02: None 00.0: 11001 VESA Framebuffer
[Created at bios.459]
Unique ID: rdCR.99a6Uj8yMKC
Hardware Class: framebuffer
Model: "ATI R128"
Vendor: "ATI Technologies Inc."
Device: "R128"
SubVendor: "ATI RAGE128"
SubDevice:
Revision: "01.00"
Memory Size: 32 MB
Memory Range: 0xe4000000-0xe5ffffff (rw)
Mode 0x0382: 320x200 (+320), 8 bits
Mode 0x030d: 320x200 (+640), 15 bits
Mode 0x030e: 320x200 (+640), 16 bits
Mode 0x030f: 320x200 (+960), 24 bits
Mode 0x0320: 320x200 (+1280), 24 bits
Mode 0x0392: 320x240 (+320), 8 bits
Mode 0x0393: 320x240 (+640), 15 bits
Mode 0x0394: 320x240 (+640), 16 bits
Mode 0x0395: 320x240 (+960), 24 bits
Mode 0x0396: 320x240 (+1280), 24 bits
Mode 0x03a2: 400x300 (+400), 8 bits
Mode 0x03a3: 400x300 (+800), 15 bits
Mode 0x03a4: 400x300 (+800), 16 bits
Mode 0x03a5: 400x300 (+1200), 24 bits
Mode 0x03a6: 400x300 (+1600), 24 bits
Mode 0x03b2: 512x384 (+512), 8 bits
Mode 0x03b3: 512x384 (+1024), 15 bits
Mode 0x03b4: 512x384 (+1024), 16 bits
Mode 0x03b5: 512x384 (+1536), 24 bits
Mode 0x03b6: 512x384 (+2048), 24 bits
Mode 0x03c2: 640x350 (+640), 8 bits
Mode 0x03c3: 640x350 (+1280), 15 bits
Mode 0x03c4: 640x350 (+1280), 16 bits
Mode 0x03c5: 640x350 (+1920), 24 bits
Mode 0x03c6: 640x350 (+2560), 24 bits
Mode 0x0300: 640x400 (+640), 8 bits
Mode 0x0383: 640x400 (+1280), 15 bits
Mode 0x0384: 640x400 (+1280), 16 bits
Mode 0x0385: 640x400 (+1920), 24 bits
Mode 0x0386: 640x400 (+2560), 24 bits
Mode 0x0301: 640x480 (+640), 8 bits
Mode 0x0310: 640x480 (+1280), 15 bits
Mode 0x0311: 640x480 (+1280), 16 bits
Mode 0x0312: 640x480 (+1920), 24 bits
Mode 0x0321: 640x480 (+2560), 24 bits
Mode 0x0303: 800x600 (+800), 8 bits
Mode 0x0313: 800x600 (+1600), 15 bits
Mode 0x0314: 800x600 (+1600), 16 bits
Mode 0x0315: 800x600 (+2400), 24 bits
Mode 0x0322: 800x600 (+3200), 24 bits
Mode 0x0305: 1024x768 (+1024), 8 bits
Mode 0x0316: 1024x768 (+2048), 15 bits
Mode 0x0317: 1024x768 (+2048), 16 bits
Mode 0x0318: 1024x768 (+3072), 24 bits
Mode 0x0323: 1024x768 (+4096), 24 bits
Mode 0x0307: 1280x1024 (+1280), 8 bits
Mode 0x0319: 1280x1024 (+2560), 15 bits
Mode 0x031a: 1280x1024 (+2560), 16 bits
Mode 0x031b: 1280x1024 (+3840), 24 bits
Mode 0x0324: 1280x1024 (+5120), 24 bits
Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

So it seems that the graphics card does not support the requested mode.

Is there a way to get the mode currently used by the console?

The only reference I found for a similar issue is [cannot display this video mode optimum resolution 1280x1024 60hz](https://superuser.com/questions/808964/cannot-display-this-video-mode-optimum-resolution-1280x1024-60hz), which however is about windows and has no solution.

EDIT: The debian graphical installer (netinst version) displays as well; so if I could find out which resolution it uses, I could set that one.

Comment: What is the model of your monitor? Some monitors can't use certain resolutions

Comment: [Text mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode) is often very different to the graphic modes...
So "_Is there a way to get the mode currently used by the console?_" - That's probably not something you want to do, or even could do with regards to running X11 on that display mode.

Comment: Have you tried any of the resolutions listed? e.g: 1280x1024 @24bit

Comment: @gregg that is what i think, and that's why I wanted to find out the resolution used by in text mode, which should be supported  (since I can use it).

Comment: @Attie I set that one in grub options (GRUB_GFXMODE and GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX), but nothing changed; I also tried the approach proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73804/wrong-login-screen-resolution), but I could not find the right "--output" option (VGA0 to VGA2 didn't work)

Comment: @Attie However the issue is that the monitor doesn't support the resolution used by X (which I suppose is one of those listed), and it asks to change the resolution to something that don't appear to be supported by the GPU. However, since the console and the Debian installer could be displayed, there must be some lower resolution supported by the monitor, and I want to find out which is that resolution.

Comment: `1920x1080@60Hz` is not listed...

Comment: @NULL I agree that if debian installer GUI worked there must be some resolution monitor supports. The monitors manual will detail the supported resolutions then you can just try those in order

Comment: @Attie That's why I think it is not supported by the GPU. Am I right?